# Converting List of 3 Element Tuple to Dictionary

Tags: python

If I have two List of tuples

```
tuple2list=[(4, 21), (5, 10), (3, 8), (6, 7)]

tuple3list=[(4, 180, 21), (5, 90, 10), (3, 270, 8), (6, 0, 7)]
```

How do I convert it to a dictionary as below,

```
tuple2list2dict={4:21, 5:10, 3:8, 6:7}

tuple3list2dict={4: {180:21}, 5:{90:10}, 3:{270:8}, 6:{0:7}}
```

I know how to do it for 2 elements in tuples, using,

```
tuple2list2dict=dict((x[0], index) for index,x in enumerate(tuple2list))
```

But for 3 elements I have problem, have error trying the below,

```
tuple3list2dict=dict((x[0], dict(x[1], index)) for index,x in enumerate(tuple3list))
```

How do I reuse the above code for 3 element tuple to create a dictionary?

Any pointer appreciated or point me where I could read more on this. Have trouble finding it in the internet.

Comment: Python variable names can't start with integers.

Comment: Your "3tuplelist2dict" is a dict with the key `4` listed twice. That is not a valid Python dict. "2tuplelist2dict" suffers the same problem.

Comment: @unutbu and GWW -- Sorry I have made some typos. Have duly corrected it above. Thanks for highlighting

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Python2.7 or newer, you could use a dict comprehension:

```
In [100]: tuplelist = [(4, 180, 21), (5, 90, 10), (3, 270, 8), (4, 0, 7)]

In [101]: tuplelist2dict = {a:{b:c} for a,b,c in tuplelist}

In [102]: tuplelist2dict
Out[102]: {3: {270: 8}, 4: {0: 7}, 5: {90: 10}}
```

In Python2.6 or older, the equivalent would be

```
In [26]: tuplelist2dict = dict((a,{b:c}) for a,b,c in tuplelist)
```

Note that if the first value in the tuples occurs more than once, (as in the example above) the resulting `tuplelist2dict` only contains one key-value pair -- corresponding to the *last* tuple with the shared key.

Comment: Is there anyway for it not to be overridden and preserve all {key:{key:value}} pairs.

Comment: In that case, you can not use a dict. You would have to use tuples, or lists.

Comment: Or, on second though, you could use a dict, if the value were a list. For example, `{4: [{0:7}, {180:21}]}`.

Answer (score 3):

This pair-case is simple, since it aligns with [dict construction](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> ... the positional argument must be an iterator object. Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterator with **exactly two objects**. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

```
>>> t = [(4, 21), (5, 10), (3, 8), (4, 7)]
>>> dict(t)
{3: 8, 4: 7, 5: 10}
```

The triple case could be solved in this way:

```
>>> t = [(4, 180, 21), (5, 90, 10), (3, 270, 8), (4, 0, 7)]
>>> dict([ (k, [v, w]) for k, v, w in t ])
{3: [270, 8], 4: [0, 7], 5: [90, 10]}
```

Or a bit more general:

```
>>> dict([ (k[0], k[1:]) for k in t ]) # hello car, hi cdr
{3: (270, 8), 4: (0, 7), 5: (90, 10)}
```

Note that your code:

```
_3_tuplelist_to_dict = {4: {180:21}, 5:{90:10}, 3:{270:8}, 4:{0:7}}
```

is really just a confusing representation of this:

```
{3: {270: 8}, 4: {0: 7}, 5: {90: 10}}
```

Try:

```
>>> {4: {180:21}, 5:{90:10}, 3:{270:8}, 4:{0:7}} == \
    {3: {270: 8}, 4: {0: 7}, 5: {90: 10}}
True
```

With Python 3, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> t = [(4, 180, 21), (5, 90, 10), (3, 270, 8), (4, 0, 7)]
>>> {key: values for key, *values in t}
{3: [270, 8], 4: [0, 7], 5: [90, 10]}
```

Comment: Note in 3.x, extended unpacking exists so one can simply do ``{key: values for key, *values in t}`` for the general case, which reads very nicely.

Comment: @Lattyware, indeed nice, thanks for the hint, updated my answer.

Comment: @miku Thanks for your comments, learnt new things. I have made typos on 4 and the variable name, have duly corrected it above. Is it possible for the tuple3list to create a dictionary with {key{key:value}} relationship as in tuple3list2dict ? Do point to me if there is any examples which I can readyly read.

Answer (score 3):

If one wants a nested dictionary without overriding the dictionary, could use the `defaultdict` from the `collections` library.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> # Edited the list a bit to show when overrides
>>> tuple3list=[(4, 180, 21), (4, 90, 10), (3, 270, 8), (6, 0, 7)]
>>> tuple3dict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for x, y, z in tuple3list:
...     tuple3dict[x][y] = z
... 
>>> print(tuple3dict)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {4: {180: 21, 90: 10}, 3: {270: 8}, 6: {0: 7}})
>>> tuple3dict[4][90]
10
```

Unfortunately, one line assignments are tricky or impossible, hence I assume the only valid solution would be this.