# How to reference multiple values in a Python dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263494/converting-list-of-3-element-tuple-to-dictionary):

```
>>> t_list = [('a', 10, 98), ('b', 234, 65), ('c', 459, 5)]
>>> t_dict = {a:{b:c} for a,b,c in t_list}
>>> t_dict
{'a': {10: 98}, 'c': {459: 5}, 'b': {234: 65}}
```

And I can call values based on the first element such as:

```
>>> t_dict['a']
{10: 98}
```

But how would I access individual values based on the key? Such as `10` or `98`. I am expecting something like this: `t_dict['a'][0]`. I have tried using `split()` and slicing it but no luck.

Comment: You are using a `dict` for the `value`, aren't you just looking for `{a: [b, c] for ...}`

Comment: Yes! should have made it into a list rather than another `dict`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
t_dict = {a:[b,c] for a,b,c in t_list}
```

Since you wanted to save b and c as a list.

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thanks! Originally, I wanted to save b and c as values which reference to `dict keys` i.e. `'a', 'b', 'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution would be this one:

```
t_dict = {t[0]: t[1:] for t in t_list}
```

And if you consider the particular case you'd have:

```
t_dict = {t[0]:t[1:3] for t in t_list}
```